# inconsistent synchronisation violation

Tags: java, multithreading, sonarqube, findbugs

I got this violation on return statement in following method:

```
protected Token getAccessToken() {  
    synchronized (this) {
        if (token == null || isExpired(token))
            token = createToken();
    }

    return token; // <-- Inconsistent synchronization of blablabla.token; locked 75% of time
}
```

Are there any visibility issues related to `token` field? As I understand after `synchronized` block token should have its latest value.

Am I missing something or it is false positive?

Comment: Perhaps, you have access to `token` somewhere else in class body w/o any sync or with synchronization using another object (not `this`)?

Comment: It's a clear read/write race between `token = createToken();` and `return token;`.

Comment: @VictorSorokin, no, `token` is only used in `getAccessToken`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following:

- Thread1: Enters method
- Thread2: Enters method
- Thread1: Enters sync block, token not null and not expired
- Thread1: Exits sync block
- Thread2: Enters sync block, token not null but expired
- Thread2: Assigns new token
- Thread1: Returns token (might be new value assigned by thread 2, might be old value)
- Thread2: Exits sync block
- Thread2: Returns (new) token

If you want to do what you are doing, then `token` might need to be volatile (but this might not be a sufficient guarantee!), or you should always return the value from the synchronized block, or assign the value of `token` to a local variable inside the synchronized block and return that local variable from outside.

This doesn't even consider what other methods might be doing to token in the meantime. If another (synchronized or unsynchronized) method modifies `token` as well (eg assigns `null`), then you might be in worse shape because you **assume** that `token` is not null (as you just checked that), while in reality it might be `null` **now**.

Comment: Just to emphasize your point to the OP, I'd like to continue your example a little further: suppose thread 1 returns the old value, and thread 2, the new. Then both threads participate in some other synchronized interaction with thread 2 using its value first, and then thread 1 with its (older) value. You could be left scratching your head, wondering how an expired token was used *after* a new token.

Comment: @erickson good point, but I guess that might even happen if you'd apply consistent synchronization here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, there are no other methods using field `token`, only `getAccessToken`. From your interaction description it seems that data race even helps! As it may return new token, while otherwise definitely expired token is returned.

Comment: @michaelnesterenko I'm not sure if that is a positive, because it might just as well not do that. However, I if this is the only method modifying token, then you have less to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

Thread A might return token that has just been recreated by thread B because the token was expired.

So thread B will write token from a synchronized block, but thread B will read it from an unsynchronized block. So yes, there might be problems. The return should be inside the synchronized block.